# How does Distinct manage to work on an IQueryable after mapping from entities to DTOs in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a query similar to this that I am running against our database:

```
var result = await _context.MyEntities
    .Select(x => new SubEntityDto { Id = x.SubEntity.Id })
    .Distinct()
    .ToListAsync();
```

The entity `SubEntity` can be the same entity set on multiple `MyEntity`.

Since I want a list of `SubEntityDto` with no duplicates, I run `.Distinct()` on the resulting `IQueryable<SubEntityDto>`. This is the `SubEntityDto` class:

```
public class SubEntityDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And this works, but I don't know how it manages to make the list distinct when working with the DTOs. Doesn't `.Distinct()` use the `.Equals` method in this scenario? And doesn't `.Equals` default to reference equality, which checks whether two instances are the same instance?

If I load the list from the database, and then do `Distinct()`, it doesn't work anymore, like this:

```
var subEntities = await _context.MyEntities
    .Select(x => new SubEntityDto { Id = x.SubEntity.Id })
    .ToListAsync();

var distinctSubEntities = subEntities.Distinct().ToList(); // Not distinct.
```

I'm thinking that it somehow manages to do this when creating the SQL for the SQL query, but can anyone tell me what is happening? I'm puzzled about the fact that it seems to keep track of the entites *after* they're mapped to DTOs.

Comment: The two queries have nothing in common. One of them gets translated to SQL, specifically `SELECT DISTINCT Id from SubEntity ....`. The second one uses `Object.Equals` unless `SubEntityDto` overloads it to find duplicates. Without an overload, it only compares references

Comment: Note that the first `Distinct()` is `Queryable.Distinct()`, while the second is `Enumerable.Distinct()`, so the first `Distinct()` is part of the query you are building.

Comment: Ah, I see. So even if the `Distinct()` comes after the `Select`, it gets translated into SQL? I'm guessing the `Select` isn't translated to SQL, so it actually rearranges the statements as it sees fit.

Comment: `var distinctSubEntities = subEntities.Distinct().ToList(); // Not distinct.` you will find it is... but just not what you wanting to do .... its distinct by memory. you want to do a distinct by x kind of like Distinct(x=>x.Id) but this doesnt exist, so you would have to write you own.. you could look at https://morelinq.github.io/, which adds a bunch of useful operations, the one they add which you would be interested in is DistinctBy

Comment: The reason the first one worked is that done on the DbContext and its translated to sql DISTINCT

Comment: Alright, but is it rearranging the `Select` and the `Distinct`? The `Select` runs after the `SELECT DISTINCT` SQL query?

Comment: Upon futher inspection, it seems like the `Select` alters the query to just return `SubEntity`. I havent found the docs for this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, when you create your query it gets translated into SQL query by your provider. So in the first case it is `Queryable.Distinct()`, however, in the second case you have already run your query against your database by calling `ToListAsync()` and result of it already translated to DTO's in memory (objects). Therefore `Enumerable.Distinct()` is run.

You can also use your debugger to see the created query
[image]

You can see the created query by your provider by putting a breakpoint and then investigating the contents of the variable DebugView→Query→Text Visualizer will show you the result.
[image]

Comment: Alright, but is it rearranging the Select and the Distinct? The Select runs after the SELECT DISTINCT SQL query?

Comment: And I can't find the same, nice view of the SQL as you show in the screenshot. Where is it hidden?

Comment: Upon futher inspection, it seems like the `Select` alters the query to just return `SubEntity`. I havent found the docs for this yet.

Comment: @ptf, You can see the created query by your provider by putting a breakpoint and then investigating the contents of the variable DebugView→Query→Text Visualizer will show you the result. I have also updated my answer as well. I also do not follow your question about altering the query with Select. If you want we can start a chat and talk it over